# 'forecast.Arima' function missing from'forecast' package

Tags: forecasting, arima

Unable to find forecast.Arima function in forecast package. Error displayed "forecast.Arima" not found. Can forecast function be used in place of   'forecast.Arima' function ? I am using forecast 8.1.

Secondly, the output from ARIMA is flat at mean for the future dates. Is this because I am using 'forecast' function.

library(forecast)

```
arima.forecast <- forecast(arima1, h=30)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`forecast.Arima` is not missing, it is just not exported in v8.1+. Use `forecast` instead, which will call `forecast.Arima` when required.

Flat forecasts are common. See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/flat-forecasts/