# Error in rep(1, n.ahead) : invalid 'times' argument in R

Tags: r, time, series, arima

I'm working on dataset to forecast with ARIMA, and I'm so close to the last step but I'm getting error and couldn't find reference to figure out what I'm missing.

I keep getting error message when I do the following command:

```
ForcastData<-forecast(fitModel,testData)

Error in rep(1, n.ahead) : invalid 'times' argument
```

I'll give brief view on the work I did where I have changed my dataset from data frame to Time series and did all tests to check volatility, and Detect if data stationary or not.
Then I got the DataAsStationary as good clean data to apply ARIMA, but since I wanna train the model on train data and test it on the other part of the data, I splitted dataset into training 70% and testing 30%:

```
ind <-sample(2, nrow(DataAsStationary), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7,0.3))
traingData<- DataStationary1[ind==1,]
testData<- DataStationary1[ind==2,]
```

I used Automatic Selection Algorithm and found that Arima(2,0,3) is the best.

```
autoARIMAFastTrain1<- auto.arima(traingData, trace= TRUE, ic ="aicc", approximation = FALSE, stepwise = FALSE)
```

I have to mentioned that I did check the if residuals are Uncorrelated (White Noise) and deal with it.

```
library(tseries)
library(astsa)
library(forecast)
```

After that I used the training dataset to fit the model:

```
fitModel <- Arima(traingData, order=c(2,0,3))
fitted(fitModel)

ForcastData<-forecast(fitModel,testData)
output <- cbind(testData, ForcastData)
accuracy(testData, ForcastData) 
plot(outp)
```

Couldn't find any resource about the error:

> Error in rep(1, n.ahead) : invalid 'times' argument

Any suggestions!! Really

I tried

```
ForcastData<-forecast.Arima(fitModel,testData)
```

but I get error that

> forecast.Arima not found !

Any idea why I get the error?

Comment: Regarding your `forecast.Arima` not found error, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201678/8386140) to a different question regarding the `forecast` package

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the arguments to `forecast()` a little differently; since you didn't post example data, I'll demonstrate with the `gold` dataset in the `forecast` package:

```
library(forecast)
data(gold)
trainingData <- gold[1:554]
testData <- gold[555:1108]
fitModel <- Arima(trainingData, order=c(2, 0, 3))
ForcastData <- forecast(fitModel, testData)
# Error in rep(1, n.ahead) : invalid 'times' argument
ForcastData <- forecast(object=testData, model=fitModel) # no error
accuracy(f=ForcastData) # you only need to give ForcastData; see help(accuracy)
                    ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE      MAPE     MASE
Training set 0.4751156 6.951257 3.286692 0.09488746 0.7316996 1.000819
                   ACF1
Training set -0.2386402
```

You may want to spend some time with the `forecast` [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf) to see what the arguments for the various functions are named and in what order they appear.

Regarding your `forecast.Arima` not found error, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193907/forecast-arima-function-missing-fromforecast-package/45201678#45201678) to a different question regarding the forecast package -- essentially that function isn't meant to be called by the user, but rather called by the `forecast` function.

EDIT:

After receiving your comment, it seems the following might help:

```
library(forecast)
# Read in the data
full_data <- read.csv('~/Downloads/onevalue1.csv')
full_data$UnixHour <- as.Date(full_data$UnixHour)
# Split the sample
training_indices <- 1:floor(0.7 * nrow(full_data))
training_data <- full_data$Lane1Flow[training_indices]
test_data <- full_data$Lane1Flow[-training_indices]
# Use automatic model selection:
autoARIMAFastTrain1 <- auto.arima(training_data, trace=TRUE, ic ="aicc",
                                  approximation=FALSE, stepwise=FALSE)
# Fit the model on test data:
fit_model <- Arima(training_data, order=c(2, 0, 3))
# Do forecasting
forecast_data <- forecast(object=test_data, model=fit_model)
# And plot the forecasted values vs. the actual test data:
plot(x=test_data, y=forecast_data$fitted, xlab='Actual', ylab='Predicted')
```

[image]

```
# It could help more to look at the following plot:
plot(test_data, type='l', col=rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha=0.7),
     xlab='Time', ylab='Value', xaxt='n', ylim=c(0, max(forecast_data$fitted)))
ticks <- seq(from=1, to=length(test_data), by=floor(length(test_data)/4))
times <- full_data$UnixHour[-training_indices]
axis(1, lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1, at=ticks, labels=times[ticks])
lines(forecast_data$fitted, col=rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha=0.7))
legend('topright', legend=c('Actual', 'Predicted'), col=c('blue', 'red'),
       lty=1, bty='n')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using this dataset https://ufile.io/i526y and I have done:             ForcastData <- forecast(object=testData, model=fitModel) # no error,                 I've gone through many documentation about Time Series and forecast package, and need to get the final prediction to compare it to the actual, and now I get this error :                                                                      Error in error(x,..) : 
improper length of one or more arguments to merge.xts                              I wanted to get plot the ForcastData and test data to compare how strong Aroma mode. Any help

Comment: the data has been changed when I uploaded it where the index column was look like 2017-07-17 01:00:00  not 1,2,3...                                                          please see pic of how data looks like : https://ufile.io/6m5mg  because I want show date and time on plot and I have set the UnixHour column last index when I set data in Time Series : DataTS <- as.xts(x = DataNotTS[, -1], order.by = DataNotTS$UnixHour, frequency = 4)
Here the link of the data with 2 columns : UnixHour and Lane1Flow https://ufile.io/kui6p  and this a link of the whole code I used : https://ufile.io/aujex

Comment: I want to convert data into Time Series and train build Arima model then train the data and test it and show the then forecast data and compare the forecasting data with actual data on plot showing data and time too, I've went through a lot and worked on this for almost month to understand the whole concept and need to finalize the result but I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run

```
ForcastData <- forecast(object=testData, model=fitModel)
```

without no error 
and Now want to plot the testData and the forecasting data and check if my model is accurate:

so I did:

output <- cbind(testData, ForcastData)
plot(output)
and gave me the error:

```
Error in error(x, ...) : 
  improper length of one or more arguments to merge.xts
```

So when I checked ForcastData, it gave the output:

```
> ForcastData
        Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
2293201    -20.2831770 -308.7474 268.1810 -461.4511 420.8847
2296801    -20.1765782 -346.6400 306.2868 -519.4593 479.1061
2300401    -18.3975657 -348.8556 312.0605 -523.7896 486.9945
2304001     -2.2829565 -332.7483 328.1824 -507.6860 503.1201
2307601      2.7023277 -327.8611 333.2658 -502.8509 508.2555
2311201      4.5777316 -328.6756 337.8311 -505.0893 514.2447
2314801      4.3198927 -331.4470 340.0868 -509.1913 517.8310
2318401      3.8277285 -332.7898 340.4453 -510.9844 518.6398
2322001      1.4364973 -335.2403 338.1133 -513.4662 516.3392
2325601     -0.4013561 -337.0807 336.2780 -515.3080 514.5053
```

I thought I will get list of result as I have in my testData. I need to get the chart that shows 2 lines of actual data(testData), and expected data(ForcastData).
I have really went through many documentation about forcast, but I can't find something explain what I wanna do.