# I got this tpye error from when i using this forecast.Arima?

Tags: r

myforecasts=forecast.Arima(mymodel1,xreg=xfut1)
Error in forecast.Arima(mymodel1, xreg = xfut1) : 
  could not find function

Comment: did you load the required package?

Comment: yes i loaded all the required package

Comment: Check if this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193907/forecast-arima-function-missing-fromforecast-package

Comment: it will come again and again using ur suggestion code also

Comment: You need to share more code about what you tried. Also, info on the package versions that you are using. Please share complete code from loading library till the model building command which leads to error. Share it in the question description and not in the comment.