# After I library the forecast package, I got an error said could not find function "forecast.Arima", why?

Tags: r

My code is:

```
install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)
fit<-auto.arima(pricetimeseries)
summary(fit)
pricetimeseriesarima<-arima(pricetimeseries, order=c(0,1,1))
forecast.Arima(pricetimeseriesarima), h=5, level=c(99.5))
```

then

```
Error in forecast.Arima(pricetimeseriesarima, h = 5, level = c(99.5)) : 
could not find function "forecast.Arima"
```

I install the package correctly, and library it, except forecast.Arima cannot work, there are also other forecast.function cannot use, like forecast.lm, forecast.HoltWinters, etc.

So, what's the problem here, how can I solve it, if anybody can help me, that would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Are you the function is called `forecast.Arima` ? I think it could be just `Arima` ...

Comment: There is forecast.Arima function in the package, I confirm it from the official website, also, I use the code "methods(forecast)", it's definitely in the package. I try to use just Arima, cannot get what I want.

Comment: May be see this : ['forecast.Arima' function missing from'forecast' package
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193907/forecast-arima-function-missing-fromforecast-package)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I don't understand it, anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No point in using `forecast.x()`, just use `forecast()` as stated by Rob Hyndman in the URL from the comments ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193907/forecast-arima-function-missing-fromforecast-package)). In addition, and as a general rule, you should perhaps use `forecast::Arima()` rather than `stats::arima()` as stated in [Hyndman and Athanasopoulos (2014)](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7):

> There is another function arima() in R which also fits an ARIMA model. However, it does not allow for the constant c unless d=0, and it does not return everything required for the forecast() function. Finally, it does not allow the estimated model to be applied to new data (which is useful for checking forecast accuracy). Consequently, it is recommended that you use Arima() instead.

Consequently:

```
set.seed(100)
pricetimeseries <- rnorm(100)
pricetimeseriesarima <- Arima(pricetimeseries, order=c(0,1,1))
forecast(pricetimeseriesarima, h=5, level=c(99.5))
```

*Hyndman, Rob J., and George Athanasopoulos. Forecasting: principles and practice. OTexts, 2014.*